# Self complementary Graph in Planar Graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Is there any construction or enumeration to get self complementary Planar Graphs?

With some examples would be helpful

Comment: Are you already familiar with one such example?

Comment: Yes... C5 is an example for self complementary planar graph

Comment: Including context, such as an example of what you are asking about, is helpful to Readers.